# Sass/Susy mixin issue

Tags: css, sass, susy

I wanted to make a mixin for column spanning containers in SASS using the Susy framework where I could just use an include in a div and use the span-columns such as this:

```
@mixin container($columns, $ofColumns) {
    @include span-columns($columns,$ofColumns);
}
```

Then in CSS use it like this:

```
#foo {
    @include container(4,12);
}
```

But I get the error in the output css 'Mixin container is missing argument $columns.' What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/496da6cc771b6c120fe6

Comment: Could it be a version issue? Im using Compass 0.12.6, Sass 3.3.7, Susy 1.0.7

Comment: You can't be using Sass 3.3.7, because Compass 0.12 requires Sass 3.2.  That won't make it not work, though.  You would have to have another mixin called container declared after your mixin where neither the 1st nor 2nd argument is named `$columns`.

Comment: Have 2 versions of SASS installed, thanks, got that fixed. So what I have above should work, except in the case you described?

Comment: Assuming the other mixins you're referencing exist and are being used correctly, yes.

Comment: I changed the container name, worked. Not sure why 'container' didn't I guess it may be in use somewhere in SASS under the hood?

Comment: If you want some internet points, post your reply as an answer and Ill give you the old star treatment

Comment: Sass, no.  Susy, probably.  You do know that there is a newer version of Susy, etc., right?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have time for the learning curve in the middle of this project. Will use new Susy next time. Do you like it better than 1.x?